# Методы класса по умолчанию

Tags: c++

Какие методы классы обязательно присутствуют в классе? Я знаю следующие:

```
конструктор по умолчанию
конструктор копирования
деструктор
операция присваивания
```

Что еще создается компилятором?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Перемещающий конструктор и перемещающее присваивание.

Comment: присваивание уже было, а что за перемещающий конструктор? Что он делает?

Comment: @AndrejLevkovitch, перемещающее присваивание, а не копирующее. Это С++11+, там [появилась возможность](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B11#%D0%A1%D1%81%D1%8B%D0%BB%D0%BA%D0%B8_%D0%BD%D0%B0_%D0%B2%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5_%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%8A%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D1%8B_%D0%B8_%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0_%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%B0_(Rvalue_Reference/Move_semantics)) дешево передавать владение внутренними данными объекта при копировании, что особенно актуально для временных объектов (rvalue).

Comment: @AndrejLevkovitch `Class(Class&& other)` и `Class& operator=(Class&& other)`

Comment: Обычно компилятор создает отдельную vtable для каждого класса, если есть наследование и виртуальные методы. В добавок к перечисленным...